# Facebook API's fail on devices but not emulator

Tags: android, facebook, android-binder

I have a Facebook 2.0 app and I am trying to upgrade to 3.0.  I downloaded the new SDK but when I try to run the sample apps on my Samsung S3 or Note devices it fails with either of these errors depending on the app:

```
E/SpannableStringBuilder(31569): SPAN_EXCLUSIVE_EXCLUSIVE spans cannot have a zero length

E/JavaBinder(32460): !!! FAILED BINDER TRANSACTION !!!
```

The weird thing is that if I try to run the test apps through the emulator they work.  I read some posts that say some manufacturers modify the Facebook app that comes with the device so I'm thinking this might be the issue.  Does anyone have any ideas or has this happened to any of you?

Comment: Can you please post your Logcat here?

Comment: Facebook 2.0 is deprecated from june 2013.No more support for version below Facebook 3.0. So download latest Facebook SDK and start with new API

Comment: @BirajZalavadia `Facebook 2.0 is deprecated from june 2013.No more support for version below Facebook 3.0. So download latest Facebook SDK and start with new API`: I think that's what OP is trying to do.

Comment: Correct I am trying to convert my current 2.0 app to 3.0 and trying to get samples working because my changes are not.  Also generated a new Android hash key per the docs and put the key in the sample app settings in the Facebook Developer Console.

Comment: I also put some log statements in my own code.  When the user requests to view their friends I do the following code

Comment: 'Session session = Session.getActiveSession();
     
      if (!session.isOpened() && !session.isClosed()) {
        Log.e("Session is not opened", "Session is not closed");
        session.openForRead(new Session.OpenRequest(this).setCallback(statusCallback));
      } else {
       Log.e("Open Active Session", "Status Callback");
          Session.openActiveSession(this, true, statusCallback);          
      }'

Comment: Every time it says it is not opened.  I get a popup dialog that asks to access your public profile and I press yes.  I also put a log statement in the statusCallback class and it always shows a state of "opening" but never anything else and no other messages in the logcat so it's almost like its hung up somewhere.

Comment: Your problem is your sdk of facebook. Download the newest sdk from their site and all will work well

Comment: @Chris You got the solution now?